# I am trying to make a summation of three matrix

Tags: r

I am trying to make a matrix form such as

Summation from `j=0` to `30` `[ (A^j%*%V%*%t(A)^j) ]`. and `A` and `V` is `3` by `3` matrix.
therefore, the result should be 3 by 3 matrix form.

for example

```
A=matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)
V=matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)
```

and I tried

```
for (i in 0:30) {
    AVA=sum(A^i%*%V%*%t(A)^i)
}
```

but it is not working.

Do you have any idea how to do summation of matrix as above?

Comment: Do you want to compute the sum of all sums?

Comment: I am trying to sum (A^0%*%V%*%A^0 +A^1%*%V%*%A^1 + A^2%*%V%*%A^2 + ..... +A^30%*%V%*%A^30). thanks

Comment: By `^i` do you mean matrix power, or taking each element of the matrix to the `i`th power? Having seen one of the other answers I realize I assumed the former with mine.

Comment: i is matrix power. thanks

Comment: I am sorry but I realized that i is not power. So for example A^2 is A%*%A, not A^2. Do you have any idea how to fix for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
A=matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)
V=matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)
AVA=matrix(rep(0,9), ncol = 3)
Atopoweri = diag(3) # A to zeroth power
for (i in 0:n) {
    AVA = AVA + Atopoweri%*%V%*%t(Atopoweri)
    Atopoweri = Atopoweri %*% A
}
```

I'm assuming by `^` you mean matrix power, but if you mean element-wise power then something along the lines of @C Doan's answer is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
AVA=matrix(0,ncol=3,nrow=3)
for(i in 0:30) AVA=AVA + A^i %*% V %*% t(A)^i
```

This will return a summation matrix for you, not a summation of all elements into an integer

Comment: As TooTone suggested, you should consider about the power of matrix (in his way) or power of matrix element (in my way) Cheers!